# How to prevent text from exiting the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, split, textview

My question is simple:If i have a text view and the text is too long,it just goes past the screen limit,how can i make it to split on multiple lines in order for it to fit in the screen

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_cast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/movie_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/movie_rating_bar"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Cast: Ryan Reynolds,Dwayne Johnson,Gal Gadot"/>
```

And also,why does some text fit on my emulator screen and when i run the app on my phone it doesn't fit,why isn't it resizing acordingly.Look at how the text just gets out of the screen without going on the next line

[image]

Comment: It will split the text automatically unless you have the singleLine attribute set.  You may want to post your xml

Comment: It doesn't split it,i'll post it right now

Comment: Is it not splitting on the emulator/device when you run the app, or not splitting in the design view?

Comment: Not spliting on emulator and device.Apperently it's splitting in the design view,but only after it get's past the screen limit with a couple words,not as soon as it reacheas the limit

Comment: You've set the ``TextView`` width to ``wrap_content``, so it's stretching out past the edge of the screen (which it doesn't care about, you haven't constrained it to that) as wide as necessary to fit the text in one line. That's what ``wrap_content`` does - stretches as big as big as it needs to be. You don't want that - you want to **limit** the width by setting a constraint (i.e. constraining the end to the end of the parent, locking the edge to the edge of the screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using `ConstraintLayout` , instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` use `android:layout_width="0dp"` and fix `start` and `end` of layout according to constraints.

Comment: And this will fit the text acording to the screen size?

Comment: @DragosCiupe Yes as it will not try to wrap full text inside textview, It may add lines for overflow test , add `android:single_line="true" && android:wllipsize="end"` .

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute to textview

```
 app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_cast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"  // this line 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/movie_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/movie_rating_bar"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Cast: Ryan Reynolds,Dwayne Johnson,Gal Gadot"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're constraining the start but not the end of the view.  Constrain the end as well, so it knows when to end the textview.  Without a constraint on the end, and with a wrap_content length, it will make the text view as large as wide as necessary to fit all the text.